# reading from ms access database to display on form using vb

Tags: ms-access, vb6

i have two forms named (Auction,Bidding) and 2 tables named (AuctionTBL,BiddingTBL)..they both have the same labels and text boxes(e.g Productname-textbox1,productcolour-textbox2,productgrade-textbox3)....NOW,,when i fill data into Auction form and save,it stores it at AuctionTBL in the ms access database, i want the data stored at AuctionTBL to display on Bidding form when i run my program....i have tried using the sub display, i can read the data to display back on the auction form..but i want it to display on the bidding form...thanks..

Comment: We need more details about your tables design and you also need to explain a bit more how the final resulting form should look like.

Comment: my auction form : contains product ID, product name,product color, product version,product price,product grade                                           my bidding form : contains product ID, product name,product color, product version,product price,product grade,bidding price.................so what i want is when i save details of auction form and it stores in AuctionTBLdb, those details should display on Bidding form when the project is run...so that i can input My bidding price and save it now to BiddingTBL..

Answer (score 0):

Please dont post a question without showing the code you tried first, but since this is easy and I was just dealing with it I will show you an example
For writing use this code

```
With db.recordset
.AddNew
.Fields("someField") = text1.text
.Update
End With
```

Hope this helps.